# Coding custom shape

Tags: html

I have little bit of my webdesign and now i don't know, how to code this:

[image: odd shape]

On white background is header and on red background is next part of webdesign. I don't know how to code this shape.

Can someone help me with this please?

Thanks

Comment: nothing yet, i dont know how to start...

Answer (score 2):

The tricky part with this layout is obviously the slant, but as [CSS-Tricks demonstrates](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/), you can use borders to achieve slants.

Thus, with a simple div positioned at the right edge of the upper portion of the header (or whatever element), you can get a slant that is backwards compatible all the way to IE 7 - with an HTML5 shiv (since it doesn't use transformations):

```css
 header {
   background: #c33;
   height: 100px;
   margin-top: 80px;
   position: relative;
 }
 div.top {
   position: absolute;
   height: 40px;
   width: 50%;
   top: -40px;
   background: inherit;
   left: 0;
 }
 div.triangle {
   position: absolute;
   top: -40px;
   left: 50%;
   border: transparent 20px solid;
   border-bottom: #c33 20px solid;
   border-left: #c33 20px solid;
   height: 0;
 }
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</header>
```

Comment: That is rather slick :)

Comment: don't wanna be pushy or anything, but if it works for you please don't forget to accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 boxes, then for that top slanted part, create a square and rotate it to get the right angle and place it where you need it. You could probably get tricky and create the 2 decoration parts with `:before` & `:after`